# error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'. on form array control

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have template with reactive form array item:

```
<li class="nav-main-item" formArrayName="closedStatuses" *ngFor="let item of statusesForm.get('closedStatuses')['controls']; let i = index">
    <a formGroupName="{{i}}" class="nav-main-link" href="javascript:void(0)">
      <span class="nav-main-link-name">
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input"
                type="checkbox"
                [attr.id]="'closed-' + i"
                [attr.name]="'closed-' + i"
                formControlName="checked"
                (change)="onSelectStatus()">
          <label class="form-check-label" [attr.for]="'closed-' + i">{{ item.controls.name.value }}</label>
        </div>
      </span>
    </a>
</li>
```

And I have error: `error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'. statusesForm.get('closedStatuses')['controls']`

How can I fix this error?

Comment: What happens if you try it like this? `statusesForm.get('closedStatuses')?.controls`

Comment: @Ada then I have error `Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl<any, any>'.`

Comment: Does it work if you explicitly cast it as a FormArray? `(statusesForm.get('closedStatuses') as FormArray)?.controls`

Comment: @Ada No, `error NG5002: Parser Error: Missing expected )`, I think `FormaArray` is unknown in html template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could use a helper function to get the array?

```js
getStatusControls() {
  const closedStatuses = this.statusesForm.get('closedStatuses');
  return closedStatuses ? closedStatuses['controls'] : [];
}
```

The ternary operator in the return statement should ensure that you're never trying to access `'controls'` of `null`.

```html
<li class="nav-main-item" formArrayName="closedStatuses" *ngFor="let item of getStatusControls(); let i = index">
```